# Reference public object in nested content page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

My page structure is:

```
MainNew (Master Page)
|
-->  Store (Nested Master Page)
     |
     -->  StoreCheckout.aspx (Content Page)
```

`MainNew` has the declaration

```
public LoggedInUser ThisUser { get; set; }
```

I can access this property in the `Nested Masterpage` as follows:

```
((MasterPages_MainNew)Master).ThisUser
```

But I can't seem to work out how to reference `ThisUser` from the content page.  Can anyone show me the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((MasterPages_MainNew)this.Master.Master).ThisUser
```